# Check if firebase array contains value then get all data in that index

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

So I have an array in a firebase document called ActivityLikes. It looks like this:

[image]

The collection is like this below:

```
  const db = fire.firestore();
        db.collection("eventLikes")
        .doc(eventID)
        .set({
          ActivityLikes: likes
        })
```

I have another collection which has the word "Avoca" saved, and I have this right now and I basically want to pull the data that has "Avoca" in it. So like with the name "Avoca" i can also get the imgURL. I've tried a for loop to go inside the object that firebase returns but I guess my logic is due to the fact theres multiple value and key pairs inside of it so how would i get all of the data inside of index 1 because it has the name = "Avoca".

I have the activitylikes in a hook so I have it after calling it from firebase.

I've tried like:

```
for (var i=ActivityLikes.length; i--;) {
     if (myArr[i].indexOf("Avoca")>=0) break;
}
```

I think my logic is off Im just not sure how to get all of the data inside of the index once the name matches

The other collection just looks like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqhWd.png. I know how to call this from firebase, I just need to figure out the logic for getting all the data in the array in the ActivityLikes when the name "Avoca" is present

Comment: Can you share any screenshots of that another collection and then explain what you are trying to do? You are running a loop over ActivityLikes and then want to fetch document of each name in ActivityLikes from another collection?

Comment: Hi I just have the word "Avoca" from another collection as a string and I want to do a loop that checks to see if the word avoca is in activityLikes list that I've shown above and if it is it'll return all the data inside that index so like the imgUrl and stuff because the screenshot above is just a document that contains an array @Dharmaraj

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking just for the word "Avoca" then try using `find()`:

```
// data is snapshot.data() after query
const avocaData = data.ActivityLikes.find(d => d.name === "Avoca")
```

Here avocaData will either be the first object from likes array where name is Avoca or undefined is there isn't any. After that you can use an if statement to check that and proceed with rest of the  logic.

Comment: Can I ask for some additional clarity on the answer? How does this apply to finding data in a [Firestore array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership)? Is the thought to read every document stored in the Firestore collection and then perform the find? (per the comment *snapshot.data() after query*)

Comment: @Jay from my understanding OP wanted to iterate over the "ActivityLikes" array in the document fetched and check if `name` field is "Avoca". In case there are multiple documents then yes, need to run same logic for all docs. For the `array-contains`, if you are referring to querying the documents using that operator at first place then OP will have to know the entire object that the query should look i.e. liked and imgURL field too.

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for the clarification. So it's a good answer for small datasets but won't scale with larger datasets - if the array has a million entries (which could happen over time), that's an enormous amount of data to load at one time and could overwhelm the device (causing it to crash). As long as there's a limit set to the size of the array - it's good to go. Upvote for you.